# How can i fix this Discord.Js Client Intents initialization?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I want to send a private message to every Servermember.
If i use this intents its not working.
Also not working with Intents.ALL, Intents.Guild.ALL, ...

```
`const client = new Client({intents: [
            Intents.all()
        ]});
    client.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => {
        guild.members.cache.forEach(member => {
            member.send("hi").catch(console.error);
        });
    });`
```

Tried many different intents, yet not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never use all intents, it significally slows down your bot and is a bad practise. You can read the guide on intents [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#gateway-intents) and a list of intents [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#list-of-intents).

Here's an example from the guide:

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    ],
});
```

In Discord.JS, all intents are PascalCase. Keep that in mind.